# How do I report a user for having a potentially malicious URL on their profile?

Tags: support

Say for example that someone's profile has a link that exhibits malicious behaviour such as redirecting users to other possibly malicious websites. Also assume that this url is crafted in such a way that it does not appear to be malicious (i.e. it is crafted in such a way that the url resembles what it claims to be linking to).

How would I go about reporting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How would I go about reporting this?

- Flag one of their questions/answers for moderator attention.

  If they don't have any questions/answers flag one of your **own** questions/answers.
- You can also use the "Contact" link (at the bottom of every page) and use the "Other" option.

Make sure you include a link to the profile you are concerned about and explain clearly what the problem is with the link in your message.

Comment: Couldn't contact us be used over flagging your own content?

Comment: @Ramhound I suspect that a flag would be more appropriate. Flagging a post raises the issue to the site moderators who can handle it most of the time. The _Contact_ link gets SE staff involved. Not that there's any reason SE staff cannot handle it, just that mods are more familiar with the site, have a better chance to react faster, and help keep some of the burden off SE staff, allowing them to work on bigger issues. If it becomes an issue that SE staff needs to handle, the site mods can escalate the issue through channels designed for that purpose. _New user's thoughts only, not cannon._ :|